# Unable to subscribe ros topic generated on different architecture machine

Tags: robotic-arm, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, rostopic, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm working on a project in which I am trying to use my laptop as `roscore` and using beaglebone black as ros client. I have run into some issue, I cannot make a ros topic which would be readable on both sides (beaglebone and laptop). I tried running the most simple beginner_tutorial talker.py:

1. I set `ROS_MASTER_URI` on both machines to my laptops ip address and start `roscore`.
2. On beaglebone i run `rosrun beginner_tutorials talker.py` and everything starts without any errors. I find new topic listed under `rostopic list` and everything looks fine.
3. I try to subscribe to messages using `rostopic echo /chatter` on laptop and nothing appears.
4. Running `rostopic echo /chatter` on beaglebone I can see "Hello world" messages.

Both machines are running Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Groovy installations. Beaglebone has `ros-groovy-ros-bare-bones` package and laptop has `ros-groovy-ros-desktop-full` package. It seems communication is fine, but messages is not interpreted on my laptop, maybe someone have some information why can`t I receive messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79516/unable-to-subscribe-ros-topic-generated-on-different-architecture-machine/) by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is likely a ROS environment configuration issue and not related to the machine architecture. Take a look at the [network configuration troubleshooting](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Troubleshooting#Network_Configuration) wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on 2013-09-16**:
Thank you a lot, that helped me, setting ROS_IP enviromental variable on both machines solved the problem, thanks again !